# delete, insert, and get() data from a Text widget in a class

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, text-widget

I am trying to run a script to have a button delete, insert, and potentially get() whatever data I need from a Text widget. Standard procedure tells me to just use the naming convention chosen for the widget

```
text = Text(tk), 
text.delete('1.0', END)
```

but I'm using a class to embed text within a frame and then placing that frame on a notebook "tab". Using the class and staying with the format i've chosen, I'm having hard time getting python to register any naming convention for the widget to call/edit from a different class where I'm having the button execute the script.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class Text1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, width=0, height=0, **kwargs):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height


        Frame.__init__(self, master, width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.text_widget = Text(self, **kwargs)
        self.text_widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def pack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.pack(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        self.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def grid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.grid(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid_propagate(False)

rows = 0
while rows < 50:
    root.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)

rows +=1

nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=49, sticky='NESW')
style = ttk.Style()
current_theme =style.theme_use()
style.theme_settings(current_theme, {"TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [20, 5]}}})

page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(page1, text='SS')

Text1(page1, width=470,height=400).pack()
```

Comment: There is no name by which you can refer to your Text, because you didn't give any name to the class instance that holds it.  You need to do that in the current last line of the code (and then call `.pack()` on the instance as a separate statement).

Comment: `text1 = Text1(...); text1.text_widget.delete(...)`.

Comment: And it goes without saying, as a junior amateur programmer staring at the same lines of code for hours ... I'm sure i'll make simple mistakes like this no matter how experienced i get. code works now, cheers.